# Binary search tree insert

Tags: c

I just want to `addAlbum` in the binary search tree but the tree will construct according to the release year. I wrote the code but it does not run...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct treeNode {
    int releaseYear;
    char singerName[50];
    char albumTitle[50];
    struct treeNode *left;
    struct treeNode *right;
} treeNode;

treeNode *addAlbum(treeNode *node,int releaseYear,char singerName[50],char albumTitle[50]) {
    if(node==NULL) {
        treeNode *temp;
        temp=(treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
        temp -> releaseYear=releaseYear;
        temp -> singerName[50]=singerName[50];
        temp -> albumTitle[50]=albumTitle[50];
        temp ->left = NULL;
        temp ->right = NULL;
        return temp;
    }

    if(releaseYear > (node -> releaseYear)) {
        node ->right=addAlbum(node->right,releaseYear ,singerName,albumTitle);
    }
    else if(releaseYear<(node -> releaseYear)) {
        node ->left=addAlbum(node->left,releaseYear, singerName,albumTitle);
    }
    else {
        return node;
    }

}

int main() {
    treeNode *root;
    int releaseYear;
    char singerName[50];
    char albumTitle[50];
    root=addAlbum(root,1995,"a","d");
    root=addAlbum(root,1998,"b","c");
    printf("singers = s\n",singerName[50]);
    printf("albumTitles = %c\n",albumTitle[50]);
    printf("years = %d\n",releaseYear);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: …and compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall` to compiler).

Comment: Shouldn't you be freeing the allocated space at the end?

Comment: Don't leave spaces around the arrow `->` or dot `.` operators; they bind very, very tightly and this should be reflected in the source code.  You also can't do string assignments as you attempt to; what you're doing is copying data that is out of bounds of your arrays (not good!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems:

1) You must initialize `root` to `NULL`, otherwise it may contain any garbage value and the construction of your tree can fail on first call.

```
treeNode *root = NULL;
```

2) You are assigning only one `char` of `singerName` and `albumTitle`, and both are out bounds (the valid array indices are 0…49). To copy the actual strings, use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(temp->singerName, singerName); // was: temp->singerName[50]=signerName[50];
strcpy(temp->albumTitle, albumTitle);
```

3) In case `releaseYear` is the same for two nodes, your code simply loses the new node because it is not even created. Remove the final `else` in `addAlbum` and remove the condition from the first (now only) `else`, and always return `node` if you didn't create a new one during this call:

```
if (releaseYear > node->releaseYear) {
    node->right = addAlbum(node->right, releaseYear, singerName, albumTitle);
} else {
    node->left = addAlbum(node->left, releaseYear, singerName, albumTitle);
}
return node;
```

4) Your `printf` calls in `main` just print out garbage values of uninitialized local variables. Remove all other local variables except `root` from `main`. Implement traversal of the tree to print out the values stored therein.