# Trying to make binary search trees in C, but i am not able to branch it

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Whenever a new node is being inserted, instead of branching and pointing the NewNode to the Null valued branch, its just replacing the the same nodes at height 2 with the NewNodes.

The problem occurs at line 85.

Output:

```
    Enter the data of first node: 10
    Enter the data of node: 7
     7
     L
    10
    Do you want to continue: 1
    Enter the data of node: 6
    6 
    L
    10
    Do you want to continue: 1
    Enter the data of node: 11
     11
     R
     10
     Do you want to continue: 0
```

Instead it should have worked in this way:

```
    head node=10
    first node=7
    L
    temp=10  
    second node=6
    L
    L
    temp=7
    Third node=11
    R
    Temp=10
```

meaning all the changed are occurning at head left and right nodes instead of branching out as its supposed to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*head;

void createtrees();
void treversetrees();
void addvalue(struct node *temp,struct node *NewNode);
void searchtree(int S,struct node *temp);

void main()
{
    int S;
    createtrees();
    printf("\nData in Trees is\n");
    //treversetrees();
    printf("Enter the integer to search for: ");
    scanf("%d",&S);
    struct node *temp;
    temp=head;
    searchtree(S,temp);
}

void createtrees()
{
    struct node *NewNode,*temp;
    int data,answer=1;
    head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
    if (head==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory.");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    printf("Enter the data of first node: ");
    scanf("%d",&data);
    
    head->data=data;

    do
    {
        NewNode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (NewNode==NULL)
        {
            printf("Unable to allocate memory.");\
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter the data of node: ");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        printf("\n1. %d\n",data);
        
        NewNode->data=data;
        temp=head;
        
        // printf("2\n");
        if (data<temp->data)
        {
            // printf("3.01\n");
            addvalue(temp,NewNode);
            // printf("3.1\n");
        }
        else
        {
            // printf("3.02\n");
            addvalue(temp,NewNode);
            // printf("3.2\n");
        }
        printf("Do you want to continue: ");
        scanf("%d",&answer);
    }
    while(answer==1);
}

void addvalue(struct node *temp,struct node *NewNode)
{
    // printf("4\n");
    if (temp==NULL)
    {
        temp=NewNode;
    }
    else if (NewNode->data<temp->data)
    {
        printf("L\n");
        printf("\n%d\n",temp->data);
        addvalue(temp->left,NewNode);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("R\n");
        printf("\n%d\n",temp->data);
        addvalue(temp->right,NewNode);
    }
}

void searchtree(int S,struct node *temp)
{
    if (temp->data==S)
    {
        printf("%d is found in tree",S);
        return;
    }
    else if(temp->data>S)
    {
        temp=temp->right;
        searchtree(S,temp);
    }
    else if(temp->data<S)
    {
        temp=temp->left;
        searchtree(S,temp);
    }
    else if(temp==NULL)
    {
        printf("%d is not found in tree",S);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have this `if (data<temp->data) {...} else {...}` in your `createtrees()`. It is duplicating the work that is already done in `addvalue()`

Comment: You do not assign anything to the `left` and `right` members anywhere in your code.

Comment: I recommend changing the first parameter of `addvalue` to have type `struct node **` and changing the remaining code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of functions to get you started:

```
struct node *createnode(int data)
{
    struct node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));

    if (node == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory.");
        exit(0);
    }
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
}
```

```
void addvalue(struct node **temp,struct node *NewNode)
{
    // printf("4\n");
    if ((*temp)==NULL)
    {
        (*temp)=NewNode;
    }
    else if (NewNode->data<(*temp)->data)
    {
        printf("L\n");
        printf("\n%d\n",(*temp)->data);
        addvalue(&(*temp)->left,NewNode);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("R\n");
        printf("\n%d\n",(*temp)->data);
        addvalue(&(*temp)->right,NewNode);
    }
}
```

You should be able to figure out the rest on your own, but you do not need to do anything special for the first node. Just initialize `head` to `NULL` and call `NewNode = createnode(data);` and  `addvalue(&head, NewNode);` for each node.

There is a null pointer dereference bug in `searchtree()` but you can
fix it by changing the order of the tests.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a good effort for someone learning C. However, there are a few small problems in the code you've recently published at the link shown in the comments to another "answer".

1. Not verifying the success of dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()`).
2. Duplication of code (there's nothing special about the root node.)
3. `searchtree()` *uses* the node pointer **before** checking if its value is NULL.
4. `if(Node->data>data)` searches down the incorrect side of the tree.
5. Program exits without releasing allocated memory (considered a *memory leak*).
6. Not checking the returned value from `scanf()`.

I've "re-worked" your recent code to make it function as I presume you want it to function.

While it's all well and good for a program to generate its own data to test functionality, it's **not** good when that testing does not fully test functionality.

By loading data from `stdin`, one can easily create one or more sets of test data to be used to evaluate a program's correctness. The data used to test the code below is contained in a file and is simple to run with:

`./a.out < test1.txt`

```
4 5 1 6 6  7 9 8 3 0 2 9 9 8
9
42
7
```

The execution results in:

```
Value '6' already stored
Value '9' already stored
Value '9' already stored
Value '8' already stored
Small to Large: 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 ->
Large to Small: 9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 ->
Value to search: search(9)..RRRR..FOUND
Value to search: search(42)..RRRRR..not found
Value to search: search(7)..RRR..FOUND
Value to search:
```

The first line of data lists values to be inserted into storage. Subsequent lines present individual values to be searched.

When developing the code, one could simply run the program and type the test data that exercises any modifications.

The code, with some comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// use 'typedef' to reduce verbiage
typedef struct n {
    int data;
    struct n *left;
    struct n *right;
} Node_t;

// use 'calloc' to ensure clean start
// use 'static' as func is a "helper" to other func's
// ALWAYS check for success of system calls!
static Node_t *nodecreate( int data ) {
    Node_t *np = calloc( 1, sizeof *np );
    if( !np ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "allocation failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    np->data = data;
    return np;
}

// use "void *" to make implementation opaque
// (could use "typedef void * Store;" if desired)
// NB: This function is not 'static'. It should be available to (and tested by) main().
// Challenge: Add one more node of data in main(),
// then call traverse() to verify the additional node is present.
void *addvalue( void *vp, int data ) {
    Node_t *np = vp;
    if( !np )
        return nodecreate( data );

#if 1 // change 1 to 0 to allow duplicates. Binary trees need not have unique nodes!
    if( data == np->data ) {
        printf( "Value '%d' already stored\n", data );
        return np;
    }
#endif

    if( data < np->data )
        np->left = addvalue( np->left, data );
    else
        np->right = addvalue( np->right, data );

    return np;
}

// somewhat simplified from your version
// binary search instead of costly recursion
// (could be muted, returning only true/false instead)
void search( void *vp, int data ) {
    Node_t *np = vp;
    printf( "search(%d)..", data );
    while( np ) {
        if( np->data == data ) {
            puts( "..FOUND" );
            return;
        }
        if( data < np->data ) { // comparison SAME AS when tree built. Be consistent!
            putchar( 'L' );
            np = np->left;
        } else {
            putchar( 'R' );
            np = np->right;
        }
    }
    puts( "..not found" );
}

// another "helper" function
static void traverse_S2L_wrk( Node_t *np ) {
    if( !np ) return;
    traverse_S2L_wrk( np->left );
    printf( "%d -> ", np->data );
    traverse_S2L_wrk( np->right );
}

// another "helper" function
static void traverse_L2S_wrk( Node_t *np ) {
    if( !np ) return;
    traverse_L2S_wrk( np->right );
    printf( "%d -> ", np->data );
    traverse_L2S_wrk( np->left );
}

// exposed "traverse" function (with "metadata")
void traverse( void *vp ) {
    Node_t *np = vp;
    printf( "Small to Large: " );
    traverse_S2L_wrk( np );
    putchar( '\n' );

    printf( "Large to Small: " );
    traverse_L2S_wrk( np );
    putchar( '\n' );
}

// good programs release resources before exiting
void release( void *vp ) {
    Node_t *np = vp;
    if( !np ) return;
    release( np->left );
    release( np->right );
    free( np );
}

// NB: there's nothing "special" about the root node
void *createFromTestData( void ) {
    Node_t *np = NULL;

    char buf[ 1024 ];
    fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin );
    for( char *cp = buf; (cp = strtok( cp, " ,;" )) != NULL; cp = NULL )
        np = addvalue( np, strtol( cp, NULL, 10 ) );
        // Challenge: Don't build a tree if there is no data supplied.
        // As it is, the above will happily create 1 node with the value 0.

    return np;
}

int main( void ) {
    void *p = createFromTestData();

    traverse( p );
    
    for( ;; ) { // perform multiple tests...
        char buf[ 64 ];
        printf( "Value to search: " );
        if( !fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin ) )
            break;
        search( p, strtol( buf, NULL, 10 ) );
    }

    release( p ); // free-up allocation

    return 0;
}
```

This code uses some library functions you need to know. Better to spend time learning what's available than to wrestle with problems trying to re-invent them. Once you're really proficient, it can be recreational to try to implement your own version of various library functions.

Regarding testing: Eventually, you may wish to add `delete( int val )` to remove a node from storage. Extending the "test data" in the file to be, for instance:

```
4 5 9 4 9 2 1 5 3 7
s 7   // means 's'earch for 7
s 6
d 9   // means 'd'elete node storing 9 (if present)
d 0
a 42  // means 'a'dd node to store 42
// and so on...
```

Testing means testing...

Finally, as an exercise, move the functions that manipulate the tree nodes into a separate source file (with appropriate publication of function prototypes in a header file `#include`'d into both `main.c` and `tree.c`.) Then, consider replacing the BST implementation with, for instance, a simple array that is dynamically resized and maintained in sorted order. `main.c`, `header.h` and the various files containing test data should need NO alteration!

**Addendum:**
Once you've got everything working, and decide that your tree **should** store duplicate data values, here's another challenge: Modify the code so that any duplicate is added, shown (traversing), and removed by using an 'instance counter' stored in the node (instead of creating extra nodes.)

Answer (score -1):

From the question's code

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*head;

void createtrees();
void treversetrees();
void addvalue(struct node *temp,struct node *NewNode);
void searchtree(int S,struct node *temp);
```

In many ways this is wrong.

`void` functions returning `void` are strange animals:

- get nothing (no arguments)
- return nothing (no return value)
- only operates on a single set of global data

  - as an example, `createtrees()` is a plural name but can only operate on the single global tree

```
void createtrees()
{
    struct node *NewNode, *temp;
    int          data, answer = 1;
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

- if you call `createtrees()` twice it will override `head` global pointer and leak memory...
- hard to debug
- hard to reuse, maybe impossible

**Never write interactive code:** it is a disaster to test. If you want to test for 20 elements at 5 scenarios and the program is still crashing do the math: hundreds of fields to enter, hours of testing. No one wants this.

**I will show you a possible way of encapsulating all tree data. A complete example with code and arguments is below. I saw code for Binary Trees --- and similar collections --- programmed the way we see at this question, and may be not a safe way to do this, so the code in this example as a whole could be useful. Or just ignored** ;)

Did you noticed that there is not even `Tree` in the code? A `node` is not a tree, as a node is not a `set` or a `linked list`. Data structures like these collections are a --- possibly empty --- set of nodes and it is easier to code if the model is closer to this.

#### about the example

This is just a toy. For illustration we will go with this

```
typedef struct st_n
{
   int          data;
   struct st_n* left;
   struct st_n* right;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
   char* name;
   Node* root;
} Tree;
```

Just a few operations here:

```
Tree* so_create(const char* name);
Tree* so_destroy(Tree* tree);
int    so_insert(int value, Tree* tree);
int    so_traverse(Tree* tree, const char* msg);
```

**These functions operates only on `Tree` and data and do as expected. There is no mention to `node` in the functions exposed to the user. The reason is to protect the implementation so we can change details with no need to change user's code. And the user can not mess things up touching the internal pointers.**

Comparing to the original posted code:

- no globals. We can operate on any number of `Trees` in the program
- `so_create` returns a new empty tree with a name, in order to permit some kind of serialization.

  - in the example provided below, input values are filtered into a minimal array of 2 trees
- `so_destroy` returns a `NULL` that can be used to **invalidate the tree pointer in the same line the tree is deleted**. In complex code it can save jobs or time or both
- `so_insert()` uses the expected paradigm of inserting a thing into a *container*, here the tree. It is easier to read
- so_traverse uses the *in_order* algorithm, so the data comes back sorted in ascending order

#### `main()` for the example

```
int main(void)
{
  const int N      = 16;  // test size
  int*      vector = vector_of_N(N);
  printf("    [0..%d in random order] Vector: ", N - 1);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1) printf("%d ", vector[i]);

  printf(
      "\n    Now creates trees with even and odd "
      "values\n");

  Tree* tree[2] = {so_create("even"), so_create("odd")};
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
      if ((vector[i] % 2) == 0)
          so_insert(vector[i], tree[0]);
      else
          so_insert(vector[i], tree[1]);

  so_traverse(tree[0], "even values");
  so_traverse(tree[1], "odd values");
  tree[0] = so_destroy(tree[0]);
  tree[1] = so_destroy(tree[1]);
  free(vector);
  return 0;
}
```

### About the code

#### generating test data

A helper function, `vector_of_N()` returns an array of small `int` for testing: all values from `0` to `(N-1)` in random order.
Maybe you can see the difference of this and to stay at the keyboard inventing data at each test as in the original code...

The values are random, can be 16 as in the example, or a few thousand in some test. It makes no difference.

```
    const int N      = 16;  // test size
    int*      vector = vector_of_N(N);
    printf("    [0..%d in random order] Vector: ", N - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1) printf("%d ", vector[i]);

    printf(
        "\n    Now creates trees with even and odd "
        "values\n");
```

This is at the start of main and displays

```
    [0..15 in random order] Vector: 9 14 3 0 5 8 1 7 6 12 2 4 10 11 13 15
    Now creates trees with even and odd values
```

#### Creating `trees`

Due to the encapsulation of `Tree` data it is easy to create any number of trees. Let us try 2 ;)

```
    Tree* tree[2] = {so_create("even"), so_create("odd")};
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        if ((vector[i] % 2) == 0)
            so_insert(vector[i], tree[0]);
        else
            so_insert(vector[i], tree[1]);
```

- Is comes in handy that trees have names inside. No messy `printf`s around
- since `so_create()` returns a simple pointer to a new tree they can be created in a single line, right into an array of trees.
- The function above provides as many data we want for testing, no interactive code.
- the `for` loops over the data
- and `if` inserts odd values in one tree and even values into another. This is just a toy, so we can see how to inforce a criteria and filter data, could be anything

```
    so_traverse(tree[0], "even values");
    so_traverse(tree[1], "odd values");
    tree[0] = so_destroy(tree[0]);
    tree[1] = so_destroy(tree[1]);
    free(vector);
```

And we traverse both trees. **But we know what to expect, since the data was inserted in random order but the contents are known in advance**. This gives some safety.
I did no testing other than this.

Then the trees are destroyed, the vector with the input data is destroyed and that is all

#### output of this code

```
    [0..15 in random order] Vector: 9 14 3 0 5 8 1 7 6 12 2 4 10 11 13 15
    Now creates trees with even and odd values
        [+] Insert 9 into tree "odd"
        [+] Insert 14 into tree "even"
        [+] Insert 3 into tree "odd"
        [+] Insert 0 into tree "even"
        [+] Insert 5 into tree "odd"
        [+] Insert 8 into tree "even"
        [+] Insert 1 into tree "odd"
        [+] Insert 7 into tree "odd"
        [+] Insert 6 into tree "even"
        [+] Insert 12 into tree "even"
        [+] Insert 2 into tree "even"
        [+] Insert 4 into tree "even"
        [+] Insert 10 into tree "even"
        [+] Insert 11 into tree "odd"
        [+] Insert 13 into tree "odd"
        [+] Insert 15 into tree "odd"

even values    Tree "even"
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14
    [--]


odd values    Tree "odd"
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15
    [--]


 Deleting 4
 Deleting 2
 Deleting 6
 Deleting 10
 Deleting 12
 Deleting 8
 Deleting 0
 Deleting 14 [at root]. "even" destroyed
 Deleting 1
 Deleting 7
 Deleting 5
 Deleting 3
 Deleting 15
 Deleting 13
 Deleting 11
 Deleting 9 [at root]. "odd" destroyed
```

Notes:

- we know that the input will be the numbers from `0` to `15` in random order.
- we see the order in wich they are inserted and at which tree, since the name is part of the tree *metadata*
- then we see the contents at each tree

  - we know the expected values in advance
  - `so_traverse()` accepts an optional `const char*` as a message. Handy in testing.
  - on delete the data referred by each node is displayed so we can have a clue of the traversal algorithm for deletion.
  - the root node is the last to be delete and it is flagged as such.

I did not implemented search since it is trivial. Please let me know if it is needed.

#### The complete code

I will not comment on the functions, I believe they are very simple and I am only trying to show a way to write this. Anyway please write about any question and I will write back in the code and post.

I will not say that this is a good solution or even a solution. But it worked --- well, worked like this --- at the first time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct st_n
{
    int          data;
    struct st_n* left;
    struct st_n* right;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    Node* root;
} Tree;

Tree* so_create(const char* name);
Tree* so_destroy(Tree* tree);
int   so_insert(int value, Tree* tree);
int   so_traverse(Tree* tree, const char* msg);

// Node* functions: not to be used outside
void so_destroy_nd(Node*);
int  so_insert_nd(int, Node*);
int  so_traverse_nd(Node* node);

// helper that returns a vector of random values from 0 to
// N-1
int* vector_of_N(size_t N);

int main(void)
{
    srand(230928);
    const int N      = 16;  // test size
    int*      vector = vector_of_N(N);
    printf("    [0..%d in random order] Vector: ", N - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1) printf("%d ", vector[i]);

    printf(
        "\n    Now creates trees with even and odd "
        "values\n");

    Tree* tree[2] = {so_create("even"), so_create("odd")};
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        if ((vector[i] % 2) == 0)
            so_insert(vector[i], tree[0]);
        else
            so_insert(vector[i], tree[1]);

    so_traverse(tree[0], "\neven values");
    so_traverse(tree[1], "\nodd values");
    tree[0] = so_destroy(tree[0]);
    tree[1] = so_destroy(tree[1]);
    free(vector);
    return 0;
}

int so_traverse(Tree* tree, const char* msg)
{
    if (tree == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("    Tree \"%s\"\n", tree->name);
    so_traverse_nd(tree->root);
    printf("\n    [--]\n\n");
    return 0;
}

int so_traverse_nd(Node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return 0;
    so_traverse_nd(node->left);
    printf("%d ", node->data);
    so_traverse_nd(node->right);
    return 0;
}

int* vector_of_N(size_t N)
{
    if (N < 2) return NULL;
    N      = N > 100 ? 100 : N;
    int* V = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1) V[i] = (int)i;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N - 1; i += 1)
    {
        int p    = 1 + (rand() % (N - i - 1));
        int temp = V[i];
        V[i]     = V[p];
        V[p]     = temp;
    }
    return V;
}

Tree* so_create(const char* name)
{
    Tree* one = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    one->name = malloc(1 + strlen(name));
    strcpy(one->name, name);
    one->root = NULL;
    return one;
}

Tree* so_destroy(Tree* tree)
{
    if (tree == NULL) return NULL;
    if (tree->root != NULL)
    {
        so_destroy_nd(tree->root->left);
        so_destroy_nd(tree->root->right);
        printf(
            "\n Deleting %d [at root]. \"%s\" destroyed",
            tree->root->data, tree->name);
    }
    free(tree->name);
    free(tree->root);
    free(tree);
    return NULL;
}

void so_destroy_nd(Node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return;
    so_destroy_nd(node->left);
    so_destroy_nd(node->right);
    printf("\n Deleting %d", node->data);
    free(node);
}

int so_insert(int value, Tree* tree)
{
    if (tree == NULL) return -1;
    fprintf(
        stderr, "\t[+] Insert %d into tree \"%s\"\n", value,
        tree->name);
    if (tree->root == NULL)
    {  // was empty
        tree->root        = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        tree->root->left  = NULL;
        tree->root->right = NULL;
        tree->root->data  = value;
        return 0;
    }
    // value was at root node
    if (tree->root->data == value) return 0;
    // insert at L or R subtree
    if (tree->root->data > value)
    {
        if (tree->root->left == NULL)
        {
            Node* nd         = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            tree->root->left = nd;
            nd->data         = value;
            nd->left         = NULL;
            nd->right        = NULL;
            return 0;
        }
        else
            return so_insert_nd(value, tree->root->left);
    }
    // new value is greater than one at root
    if (tree->root->right == NULL)
    {
        Node* nd          = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        tree->root->right = nd;
        nd->data          = value;
        nd->left          = NULL;
        nd->right         = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return so_insert_nd(value, tree->root->right);
}

int so_insert_nd(int value, Node* node)
{
    // end game
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        Node* nd  = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        nd->data  = value;
        nd->left  = NULL;
        nd->right = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
    // already here
    if (node->data == value) return 0;
    if (node->data > value)
    {
        if (node->left == NULL)
        {
            Node* nd   = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            node->left = nd;
            nd->data   = value;
            nd->left   = NULL;
            nd->right  = NULL;
            return 0;
        }
        else
            return so_insert_nd(value, node->left);
    }
    else
    {
        if (node->right == NULL)
        {
            Node* nd    = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            node->right = nd;
            nd->data    = value;
            nd->left    = NULL;
            nd->right   = NULL;
            return 0;
        }
        else
            return so_insert_nd(value, node->right);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: So my response is not useful, according to some. :) An useful response needs more than some complete programs with output and arguments --- all related to the question. I will try to improve on this one!

Comment: I do not understand why this example uses 87 lines of repetitious code in its last two functions to do what can be done with a single, simpler function (16 lines, or 19 lines if verification of malloc()'s success or failure is added)... Please explain the bloat, because it's not obvious why you've coded it that way. (metadata (printing the name) does not mean dealing with BST nodes has to be cloned. It seems this is putting the cart before the horse...) This implementation tangles up a simple BST with irrelevant _metadata_. Bloated, repetitious and unclear.

Comment: A node is a node is a node... Please explain **why** this code has **six** repetitions of (unchecked) `malloc()` and a few more statements when even a novice programmer realises there need be only **one** function to do that. As bad as this beginner's code is, even s/he realised this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134119/binary-search-tree-insert Invite you to post your "answer" code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com for a serious review.

Comment: "minimal"... Just pointing out that this code is far from "minimal"... Not a great answer. Especially not when combined with allusions to "_sw professionals, smart amateurs and well guided students_"...

Comment: @Fe2O3 You seem to be misrepresenting everything I've said. arfneto doesn't have a Code Review account, so would be a _new user on Code Review_. The qualm was with how you suggested Code Review. [Code Review is not a code shaming service](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1452), don't represent the site as such.

Comment: @arfneto Of course I read `main.c`. Yes, I understand the purpose of the 4 functions. Yes, I understand "encapsulation". "_Supreme truth_"?! Hardly... One of the nicest aspects of BST code is _code reuse_. In an imaginary future (note "imaginary"), the code needs to be modified to store `long long` instead of `int`, and maybe an additional data member (like a pointer) in each node.  How many _maintenance points_ are in your version of a simple BST solution?

Comment: You might want to name the structure something besides BTree since that is a known data structure type and I don't think the current struct represents it well (a BTree does not have one node).

Comment: @pacmaninbw right you are. I will change this! I did not like it too but was lazy to change afterwards.

Comment: @arfneto 1 instance of `tree->root->data = value;`. 5 instances of `nd->data = value;`... When another member is to be added to the node struct, a total of 6 _maintenance points_ just for this... _Tedious_ and error-prone...

Comment: @pacmaninbw I wrote the text as I was writing the code so to change code means to change many portions of the text from before :( . But I ended up changing the name. `Btree` name  was bothering me too. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: @arfneto thanks for the explanation. i realised how unnecialry bloated my code is. i shorted it out by a bit and removed the interactive structure of it. here is the changed one. i have no experince with C as its been 2 weeks since i started learning. https://onlinegdb.com/FH-264uea

Comment: The code is much better now. And being not interactive is important. No one wants to test a program typing imaginary data each time! Consider the case of `main` as I showed you: you select the size, the vector is numbered and then shuffled. All numbers goes to one of the 2 trees and you can spot if one number is duplicated or disappear just by the nature of the data. 10 or 10,000 elements

Comment: @arfneto I understand perfectly well, thank you. You've not yet clarified why there are 6(!) unchecked invocations of `malloc()` in your code. There's no problem with "interactive" data input. In fact, the "number generator" you use does **NOT** test attempting to put duplicate values into a BST. AND, you write "_there is no node_" ... What's the 2nd member of the `Tree` struct if not a node? Isn't the `Tree` struct supposed to hide the constraints??